Did Da Vinci really say, "Art is never finished, only abandoned"?
I've yet to find any source to verify this quote. Sites that list sources with quotes don't seem to include this one for Da Vinci, and others claim the quote comes from English author E. M. Forster.

Da Vinci certainly "abandoned" his fair share of artistic works. Thanks to the internet quotes get randomly attributed to the great and good (and often the foul and nasty too). It's almost impossible to prove that he didn't ever say it (although I doubt he did it in English).

Welcome to the Stack! What has your own research shown?

According to today's Wikiquote talk page for Da Vinci, the quote is quite old and nearly contemporaneous with Da Vinci, but unsourced. It wasn't actually attributed to Da Vinci until much later.
One of the commenters states that it appears in "Giorgio Vasari Le vite de' piu eccellenti architetti, pittori, et scultori italiani (aka: "The Lives") 1550, revised 1568", but unattributed. I found a copy of the original text online, but I don't have the language skills to read it to verify the user's claim.
The vintage of this claimed quote is only 31 years after Da Vinci died. It appears that Wikiquote by policy won't include it due to the lack of sourcing. The theories I would be going on with are that either the proper author of it was really Georgio Vasari, or perhaps it really was Da Vinci but we'll never know for sure. A close reading of the context around its use by Vasari may yield more information. From what I know right now, I'd probably attribute it to Vasari, with perhaps an asterix.

FWIW, I searched Google's scans of all three volumes of Vasari's work for the operative words "finita" and "abbandonata" and could not find anything resembling the quote. The oldest Italian version of the quote I could find at Google Books dates to 2014. It is of course possible that the modern quote is a paraphrasation that deviates significantly from the original, but for now I rate the historicity of the quote as 1 out of 10.

Giorgio Vasari, La terza et ultima parte delle vite degli architetori... (Florence 1550) p. 564: "Trouasi, che Lionardo per l'intelligenzia de l'arte cominciò molte cose, & nessuna mai ne fini, parendoli che la mano aggiugnere non potesse alla perfezzione de l'arte ne le cose che egli si imaginaua conciosia che si formaua nella idea alcune difficultà tanto marauigliose, che con le mani ancora che ell e fussero eccellentissime, non si sarebbono espresse mai."

Goggle's translation of the above quote: "It is found that Leonardo, through his intelligence in art, began many things and never finished any of them, it seeming to him that the hand could not reach the perfection of art in the things he imagined, since he formed in his idea some difficulties so marvelous, that with the hands, even if they were most excellent, they would never have been expressed."
